# Did Serenity really appear in Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, firefly, crossovers, cameo

Recently I ran across this image from the mini-series of Battlestar Galactica (from the scene in which Roslin is diagnosed with cancer):

[image]

My question is: **Is this really supposed to be [Serenity](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Serenity), the ship from [Firefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series))?**  And, if so, how did this happen? (An out of universe explanation is welcome, since an in-universe explanation of Serenity doing a job on Caprica seems... far-fetched.)

Comment: it wouldn't be the first time serenity escaped the firefly series. [this collection of pots and pans](http://i.imgur.com/K7qindP.jpg) in the background of "doctor horrible's sing-along blog" was cleverly arranged to look like serenity (although that's hardly surprising, since both were written by Joss Whedon).

Comment: Sci-fi writers do stuff like that a lot.  They put the Millennium Falcon into the big fight with the Borg in *Star Trek: First Contact*, for example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, that's *Serenity*. Sadly, there does not appear to be an in-universe answer.

[Jarrod Davis](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1449643/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), who was a digital artist on the episode, [revealed on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/jarrod.davis/posts/10202406841751447) that he put *Serenity* in the show on the advice of CG supervisor [Lee Stringer](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0834574/?ref_=fn_al_nm_2):

[image]

**Transcript:**

> So we on the Crew were all about cameos, and I do believe it was Lee Stringer who had the idea to put the Serenity in the show somewhere. It fell to me because I had these shots in the hospital where Laura Roslin gets her cancer diagnosis with all these windows that needed filling with spaceshippy goodness. Perfect opportunity of course.
>
> So I do it. And you've seen it. And I think, hey eventually some nerd will see this and get a chuckle out of it.

Comment: Interesting, reading the article you linked to it appears they didn't actually get permission to use the image of Serenity ahead of time.  That's part of why I was curious since Battlestar and Firefly were, I think, on different channels, different producers, different writers, etc.  I guess Zoic is the connection.

Comment: ''Serenity'' isn't the only famous starship in the first episode of ''BSG'': the other is [the USS Enterprise](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/File:Enterprise_in_fleet.jpg) -- in that case, I think it was supposed to be a blink-and-you-missed-it cameo, except that that shot was then incorporated into the opening credits :)

Comment: Apparently there is also a crossover the other direction.  There is a Colonial Viper from BSG in the Heart of Gold episode of Firefly.  I can't seem to find a screen cap of it though, so cannot confirm.

Comment: The Kodiak from *[Command & Conquer: Tiberian Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer:_Tiberian_Sun)* also [makes a cameo appearance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHL-wKkNtBo) in the final episode.

Comment: Man, the Cylons really took that whole "burn the land, boil the sea" lyric literally.